# Creeper Holes - Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Please I need help with some creeper issues on my private survival server. I want creepers to be exactly normal but **one** thing. They can't blow up grass and dirt. **Everything** else they should be able to destroy except **grass and dirt**.

Comment: Vanilla servers doesn't provide such functionnality. I don't think anyone ever made a mod/plugin allowing such control on creeper explosions, it's mostly everything or nothing.

Comment: Sadly @Hybris95 is correct. There is no functionality for what you are requesting at the moment.

Answer (score 9):

A little trick with command blocks would help in this case:

Setup:

```
/scoreboard objectives add noFuse dummy
/scoreboard objectives add Teleport dummy
```

Clock:

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,score_Teleport_min=1] clone ~10 200 ~10 ~-10 190 ~-10 ~10 ~10 ~10 filtered normal minecraft:dirt
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,score_Teleport_min=1] clone ~10 200 ~10 ~-10 190 ~-10 ~10 ~10 ~10 filtered normal minecraft:grass
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,score_Teleport_min=1] fill ~10 200 ~10 ~-10 190 ~-10 minecraft:air
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,score_Teleport_min=1]
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Creeper] noFuse 0
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Creeper] noFuse 1 {Fuse:0}
/execute @e[score_noFuse_min=1] clone ~10 ~10 ~10 ~-10 ~-10 ~-10 ~10 200 ~10
/execute @e[score_noFuse_min=1] summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Teleport",CustomNameVisible:0}
/scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand] Teleport 0
/scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand] Teleport 1 {CustomName:"Teleport"}
```

First it finds all creepers that are about to explode, then clones the area around it into the sky, then after it explodes the dirt and the grass will be cloned down and the area in the sky will be deleted.

Comment: This is very creative and clever.

Comment: BTW this will allow blocks behind the grass/dirt to be destroyed

Answer (score 4):

### Global Answer :

Vanilla servers doesn't provide such functionnality.
I don't think anyone ever made a mod/plugin allowing such control on creeper explosions, it's mostly everything or nothing.

## Multiplayer :

If you are searching for such kind of Plugin, WorldGuard provides similar functionalities, you just can't filter on specific block's IDs.

## SinglePlayer :

As Gilbert V stated, you can use `/gamerule mobGriefing false`. Like with WorldGuard you can't filter on specific blocks also.

Comment: The mobGriefing gamerule isn't just singleplayer.

Comment: Did I said so ? I just pointed out a tool that can do it in Multiplayer never intended to be exhaustive.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a server plugin called [CreeperHeal](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/creeperheal-nitnelave/) which is useful for this. Creepers still destroy things with this plugin installed. However, the terrain will regenerate after a short period. Also useful against griefers.

Answer (score 1):

```
/gamerule mobGriefing false
```

End result: creepers damage players but not blocks. This may not be exactly it is the closest i can think of for what you are after.